# How to Test the two stage translation in ARMv7 MMU?

Tags: testing, arm, verification, mmu

I have configured  TTBCR  and  TTBR for stage 1 translation. Then I configured   VTCR and VTTBR for stage 2 translation. I faced some issues like  abort but that are solved now. I would like to know from a testing   perspective   how the two stage translation in MMU will be tested when it goes   to verification stage. This I need to be sure that what I have done in    the application code is correct.

The strategy I followed is as follows

1.) configure TTBCR and TTBR0 and TTBR1
2.) switch to the non secure world
3)  configure VTCR and VTTBR

Comment: Stage 2 translation only applies to the Non-Secure world, so for starters you appear to be missing the fundamental step 4) drop down from Hyp to NS-SVC and configure the stage 1 MMU _there_.

Comment: "Stage 2 translation only applies to the Non-Secure world" That's precisely I have mentioned in my post as step 2.

Comment: ...which implies step 1 is configuring the _Secure World_ translation, and thus irrelevant to the situation.

Comment: Yes I start with  secure world only. But The TTBCR has nothing to do with setting up the secure world. I am entering it with the SCR NS bit  .

Comment: OK, that wasn't at all obvious - not least because it's a really bad idea, and not something you want to be getting into the habit of. Having Monitor mode do more than simply configure the non-secure registers to safe reset values is opening yourself up a world of compatibility problems and security holes. Anyway, the question's still not entirely clear - what does "the verification stage" entail? What exactly is being verified?

Comment: I want to verify that the VA to IPA and IPA to  PA conversion is getting done.I want to see those values

Comment: Eh? If you're running with both SCTLR.M and HCR.VM enabled and _not_ taking data aborts or locked up in a recursive prefetch abort at either level, then by definition your translations must be OK...

Comment: Ok thanks for that